# How to make live server Ratchet WebSockets work?

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

The websockets server works just fine on the localhost, but as soon as I upload it to the live server, I get an error saying:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://yourdomainname.com:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score 0):

This could be a security issue in that the Live server is not allowing the socket connection. Your system administrator may need to grant access to the 8080 port number for this socket to work.